# Guardar valor de Input en Variable

Tags: javascript

Tengo un input y un botón, quiero al hacer click al botón guardar el valor ingresado en el input en una variable.

```
<input type="number" id="precio">
<button id="guardar">Aceptar</button>
```

He intentado de esta manera pero no me ha funcionado:

```
let valor = 0;
const boton = document.getElementById("guardar");
boton = document.addeventListener("click", () => {
   let input = document.getElementById("precio")
   valor = input.value;
});
```

Comment: `boton = document.addeventListener(.....` esto cámbialo por `boton.addEventListener(..` Es al botón al que le agregas el evento, no al documento y la E de Event es con mayúsculas

Comment: cambia `boton = document.addeventListener(...)` por `boton.addEventListener(...)`, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se haria de la siguiente manera:

nuestro html

```
<input type="number" id="precio">
<button id="guardar">Aceptar</button>
```

y ahora, nuestro javascript:

```
const btnGuardar = document.getElementById("guardar");
const inputPrecio = document.getElementById("precio");

btnGuardar.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const precio = inputPrecio.value;
});
```

Espero haberte ayudado,
a seguir codeando